# How to auto adjust iframe height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I want to show some external sites in my blog by `iframe.` One thing, neither I'm the owner nor I have the access on those external sites that I am iframing. Is there any way to auto adjust the height of iframe ?

I really need this.. Please help anyway.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/01/13/103518.aspx http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/ did you search google?

Comment: is this works on different domain ?

Comment: Is this works on different domain ? I mean if want to show this page[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp] by iframeing in my blog, then will this code work ? @Edward