# how to set iframe height dynamically depending up on the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using `<iframe id='' src =" + url + " style='width:100%;border:none;'></iframe>`
I am trying to set the iframe height depending upon the content height.
If I didn't mention height for the iframe,it is taking default height.
can any one tell me how to set the iframe height depending upon content height....

Comment: Always post that which you have tried and where you are stocking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var height = $(window).height();
$('iframe').css('height', height)
});
```

In the above example, I have set window's height to iframe. As per your requirement, you can take your content's height and then set it to iframe's height.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<iframe name="i_frame" id="i_frame" src="" onload="iframeAutoSize( this.id );">
</iframe>
```

JS:

```
function iframeAutoSize( id ) {

    iframe_element = document.getElementById( id );

    if ( iframe_element ){

        var new_height = iframe_element.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        //var new_width = iframe_element.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes[2].offsetWidth;

        $("#"+id).height( new_height );
        //$("#"+id).width( new_width );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in .

```
style="height:auto;"
```