# How to get the height of iframe source url https using jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to assign a height based on iframe body content to iframe on page load using jquery.

My code is:

```
<iframe id="loginFrame" class="loginFrame" align="middle" style="border:none;float: left;margin-top: -100px; overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.example.com" width="700px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

How to set a height for a iframe on page load using jquery.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the iframe height after the iframe loads, see the code below

Jquery:

```
$("#loginFrame").load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height());
});
```