# What determines an iframe's width and height?

Tags: html, css

and how do I automate it?  I want it to expand width/height to the content that it holds.

For example in this fiddle it looks to randomly make a box that is 300px by 200px.

http://jsfiddle.net/fyaAR/

But the content is actually about 10 pages or 8.5 inches by (11*10) inches.  A page is 8.5 by 11 inches.  I know that I can set the dimensions by simply setting them in the CSS but I want them to adjust to whatever content the iframe holds, that is the content is dynamic.

**Fiddle code:**

```
<div id="community">
  <div id = "community_outer"></div>
  <div id = "community_cover"></div>
  <iframe scrolling="no" id="community_frame" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n9bsHIBk1KxGQTKgUF-NG6FRhb4LP0OHfmd4I50CFCU/pub" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: See if this question has an answer that works for your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: `iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"`

Comment: I imagine that will work for width as well.  Got to wonder why the browser does not do this for me.

Answer (score 1):

**I've encountered this MANY of times trying to easily insert APIs and whatnot externally.**

It's not as simple as one would imagine. The whole reason for iFrames is to avoid security-laden `AJAX` calls and to display `remote content`.

Because of this, your document will not have the `css` properties of that `document` taken into account, so trying to make **your page** render it full-scale is less than easy.

---

I would suggest reading into the `comments`, and the post described below:

[Link to question 9162933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Looks like you're going to have to use a `script`.

---

## Copied Most Relevant Answer @Aristos

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoaded() {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if(iFrameID) {
            // here you can make the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

Then **HTML**

```
<iframe id="idIframe" onload="iframeLoaded()" ...
```

---

**I've always had problems with this personally, so my final solution was to avoid `iFrames`, but you could perhaps make this work.**

Perhaps use one of `Google`'s available `API`s?

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#news_show_via_iframe

Comment: I am saying apparently other people have gotten it to work, but I never have. Just wanted to give you as many resources as possible for a VERY popular problem with VERY little solutions (most being a tad hackish). The point of my answer is to say I have never found anything to work consistently.