# Full Height PDF within iFrame

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am trying to get the PDF content in this page:
http://jimpix.co.uk/test.html

To take up 100% of the rest of the page, but it only takes up a small letterbox shaped portion of the screen.

I have set this CSS on all of the elements:

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The link is dead so it is not clear what is being asked anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ading to your css:

```
td{padding:0 !important;}
```

or inside your style attribute of element like so:

```
<td style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 !important;">
```

EDIT:

OK, I found that the problem is with the iframe. If you want to do it basic you could just set the height of the iframe to a static height like this:

```
iframe{
height: 1000px;
}
```

If you want the height to dynamically adjust to content you should look into a javascript/jQuery implementation. Perhaps [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have done that (page above updated to include that snippet of CSS), but it's not made any difference for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is padding (8px) of td tag from bootstrap css.
Add `padding:0` in your `<td>` tag.

`<td style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0;">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done that (page above updated), but the PDF content is still restricted to a small narrow window...