# Dynamic Height for <div> Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
       <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="slider.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

But when I decrease the screen size to small or medium, I will get white-space beneath the `<div>`.

Like This:

[image]

How can I have a dynamic height for this `<div>` to avoid the white-space?

Comment: Could you make a JSFIDDLE?  ==> [JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Can you show us the css for the embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 class?

Comment: @Godisgood 
this is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a003e7j/1/)

Comment: @DennisPriebe you can see the css [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a003e7j/1/)

Comment: With `.embed-responsive{ height: auto;}` and `.embed-responsive-item{ float:left; display:block}` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need using javascript to discover the dynamic height.

We have some functions in this links:
[make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

and call when the browser resize.

Answer (score 0):

use media query like and add it to custom css

this is just a sample

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .visible-md-block {
 display: block !important;
}
```