# set iframe height dynamically depending on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have this code

```
var c_iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
c_iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
c_iframe.setAttribute('width', '500');
c_iframe.setAttribute('height', '600'); // <----- 
c_iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
```

but I want the height to be dynamic depending on its content.

how can I do it?

**the things** is, the content of iframe is loaded per ajax, so iframe loads only once, the first time. then I will change the content by ajax -  those new contents are of different height. so, in this case, I cannot use `onload` to detect the new height.

Comment: Is the source of the iframe local? e.g. on the same domain?

Comment: @Terwanerik I can control the source, yes. It is coming from my server and can be served in other domains

Comment: @doniyor See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163087/4359029

Comment: It is when you want to set the height, then please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163087/886926

Comment: try this, 
[Another solution on stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: Use the `AJAX` `callback` function to re-execute the code is called by the `onload`

Comment: @tomloprod good point! :) thanks