# resize iframe height on different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am allowing a part of my site to be shown in another site (different domain).

My concern is to set the height of iframe to the height of its content. I could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163087/903790), but my case is cross browser case, so this doesnot work.

I tried to get the height of iframe by:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('id_iframe').contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
```

but this is giving only the visible height.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript to access content the user has loaded from another domain. It would be a security risk.

With the cooperation of the other site, you can receive a message (via `postMessage`) sent by the other site when its `load` event fires that tells you its height (and then you can resize in response to that).

It could also sent new heights when `resize` events fire in it.

Comment: ah ok. I am writing js widget, how is the approach for this?

Comment: When the `load` event fires, you read the height of the document, then `postMessage` it to the parent frame which will have an event listener waiting for the it.

Comment: so I need to work with the owner of other site, right?

Comment: Yes, hence "With the cooperation of the other site".

Comment: but one more thing. user is pasting a js snippet from my page which builds up the iframe in users page. I can send messages from that js of mine right?

Comment: If your code is running on a page, then that page can `postMessage` to any frames it is in or that are in it.