# Iframe - change height when content changes height

Tags: html, css

i have an Iframe with a height of `534px`. The content inside the Iframe has the option to `minimize` the content so the height of content changes from `534px` to maybe `20px`. How can I make my Iframe height dynamic to suit the inner content that is on show?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

After your content changes(event/action), Do This

```
    function AdjustIframe()
    {
       YouIframeId.height = YouIframeId.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
```

**`Inside your iframe, the change function.`**

```
function someChangeEvent()
{
  //at end of your code
  parent.AdjustIframe();
}
```

Comment: The action is controlled inside the Iframe, so how would I know when to action this on the page that the Iframe is included in?

Comment: It only works if OP have the control of the content in the iframe. If not, that never works.

Comment: I have access to the Iframe content.

@user3662307 I get the following error with your suggestion: `Error: Permission denied to access property "AdjustIframe"`