# How to set the iframe height according to the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set the height of the iframe according to the content.

```
<iframe src="../graphs/Average.html" alt="##graphname" width=100% height=680px overflow:visible frameborder=0 class="general" style="border-collapse: collapse;" noresize onload="document.getElementById('p').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

I have also tried:  `<style> div{overflow:visible} </style>`
But its also not working.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use following JScode:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="../graphs/Average.html" alt="#graphname" width="100%" height="680"  frameborder=0 class="general" style="border-collapse: collapse;" noresize onload="document.getElementById('p').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

**Using javascript**

```
document.getElementById("iframe").style.height = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px'
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$('#iframe').height($('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
```

Comment: With this also overflow:visible is not working. Scroll bar is coming,i need the data in full length of page not in scroll.