# How to insert JSF page into React-component?

Tags: reactjs, jsf

Can I insert **JSF**-page(table) into **react-component**?

I have old version of **application** with front-end on **JSF** and backend on Java.
Needs to create demo version with front-end on **reactJs**. So, can I create mock react-component with jsf-page in body to speed up creating of demo version.
Is it possible?

Comment: This is not speeding up a demo... This is 'facking'... ;-)

Comment: Yes,  i need just particular imlemented app to do step for upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your JSF page either as :

1. IFrame
2. Load via Ajax and Insert the code received into the HTML

There will be no dependency of react if the JSF code dosen't contain any and both methods can be used.

If JSF code itself contains some react code , just request and insert code into html

Comment: Can I split jsf page before insertion in IFrame? F.e. I have jsf page, menu items, buttons and table. So, I need to insert table only.

Comment: Yes, you can create another JSF with the required data only and insert that only.

Comment: Do you know, how to fetch iframe height with content?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov do you need to adjust height of frame with content ?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript` checkout the accepted answer. No need to focus on jquery , the code is pretty basic and can be re-written using react or plain js.