# Set iframe height from inside body

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have Iframe created dynamically on click, and the src file loaded by iframe contains huge dropdown list, I set iframe height dynamically using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript), now inside the iframe if the user click on dropdown the values are not shown completely

So, onclicking the dropdowns I will set the iframe height to show all dropdown values by calling a function

```
<a href="javascript(0)" id="dp1" onclick="setIframeHeight(this.id)">sources</a>
```

my javsctip looks like :

```
function setIframeHeight(no){
    var iFrameID = window.frameElement.id; // diplays exact id of iframe
        window.parent.document.getElementById(iFrameID).height  = '1500px';
}

/* as i get iframe id, how to set the height of the iframe. */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
window.parent.document.getElementById(iFrameID).style.height  = '1500px';
```

However, if you are trying to set the iFrame height from within the guest content AND guest_origin !== host_origin, you will have to run a function of the host to make the frame adjustment work.

Comment: This works great is there a possibility to do as `window.frameElement.id.style.height=currentheight + "100px";

Comment: Get the current height from `window.frameElement.id.style.height` and increment it as you want.