# Flutter web in an iframe with dynamic height

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I have embedded a flutter web app onto my Wordpress site. The flutter app is connected to an API and has a varying height. Is there a way to make the Iframe change its height depending on what's shown in it?

My code so far:

```
<iframe src="My-URL" height="600" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Side note, is there a way to turn off scrolling when I hover over the iframe (I still need to be able to click on it).

```
scrolling="no"
```

doesn't seem too be working.

Thankful for all answers :)

Comment: iframe dynamic height based on contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: for the side note, does this css work? `iframe:hover { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: or maybe you mean turn off parent page scrolling while hovering the iframe?

Comment: @GrafiCode `iframe:hover { overflow: hidden; }` doesn't do it. Since I want the iframe to show all of its contents no scrolling is needed. Now when I'm hovering over it and scroll nothing happens. I want to be able to scroll the whole page at that point. 

Ill try the link. Thanks!

Comment: @GrafiCode I guess flutter doesn't work like normal html/js code, the solutions from [9162933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript) isn't working in this case.