# Jquery - Dynamically resize frame from with in

Tags: jquery

In using `winbox.js` https://nextapps-de.github.io/winbox/ to create iframes and within each I'm loading local php pages which all have jquery available.

The iframe loads to a default size which is what a want, but when I follow a link within an iframe to another local php page I want to resize the iframe so it fits the contents.

I've been able to do it specifying the iframe id, width and height using the following:

```
$('#winbox-2', window.parent.document).width('900px');
$('#winbox-2', window.parent.document).height('1000px');
```

But I'd like to do this so it automatically matching the contents size so it's not fixed width/height as above.

Also I need to be able to do this dynamically to the iframe as I won't know what `id` each iframe has.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the iframe: ✌️

```js
onload="$(this).height($(this.contentWindow.document.body).find(\'div\').first().height());"
```

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801343/1510309
From duplicated question: [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't seem to make the iframe any larger.

Comment: Do you have a wrapping div inside the content?

Comment: A php page is being loaded into the iframe, so it's a full document.

Comment: The duplicated question contains much more information then I can give you at this point. You should search for your solution there. ✌️

Comment: I've got this working after manging to find out the parent iframes id. The only issue is once it has been resized if I try to manually resize it it jumps back the original size.